# Can I upgrade Dart and not Flutter version?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to upgrade my Dart version only. I currently have Dart SDK 2.17.5 and I need 2.19.0. I do not want to upgrade my Flutter version, as this would imply code changes that I don't have the time for right now.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the version of flutter determines the compatible dart that has been tested with it.  It will be hard to find a solution that does not upgrade both dart and flutter simultaneously.

If you want only the latest dart, you can continue to use your current flutter release with most projects using [`puro`](https://puro.dev), and then use puro to install the latest flutter as well, but use it only in the project in which you want to use the latest dart.

If you're not familiar with puro, it's like fvm, but I stopped using fvm entirely upon discovering puro, and never looked back.